# Unable to draw user defined shapes as part of a new class

Tags: java, image

I don't think the question is asked clearly so I'll try to explain:

I'm trying to draw a full adder with each gate being drawn as a separate sub-class; so the adder is one class and it will call the XOR gates and place them, then the and gates and so on.

Drawing the gates by themselves (and creating the components in the adder method) works out fine, but when I try to call them in the adder I receive complaints from the compiler.

Casting to a shape creates a ClassCastException; And I have no idea why the compiler dislikes drawing them.

<del>Here's a link to all my classes.</del>

**Adder.java**
    package adder;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import andGate.*;

public class Adder
{
    private final int HEIGHT = 700;
    private final int WIDTH = 1200;
    private int xLeft = 0;
    private int yTop = 0;

    /**
     * Constructs a gate with a corner at (0,0)
     */
    public Adder()
    {
        new Adder(xLeft, yTop);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a gate with the given top left corner
     * @param x the x co-ordinate of the top left point
     * @param y the y co-ordinate of the top left point
     */
    public Adder(int x, int y)
    {
        xLeft = x;
        yTop = y;
    }

    /**
     * Draw the gate
     * @param g2 the graphics context
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
         AndGate and = new AndGate();

        g2.draw(and);
    }       
}
```

**AdderComponent.java**
    package adder;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import andGate.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AdderComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Adder ad = new Adder(20, 20);

        ad.draw(g2);
    }
}
```

**AdderVeiwer.java**
    package adder;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import andGate.*;

public class AdderVeiwer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.setTitle("Full Adder");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        AdderComponent ad = new AdderComponent();
        frame.add(ad);
    }

}
```

**AndGate.java**
    package andGate;

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class AndGate
{
    private final int WIDTH = 300;
    private final int HEIGHT = 100;
    private int xLeft = 0;
    private int yTop = 0;

    /**
     * Constructs a gate with a corner at (0,0)
     */
    public AndGate()
    {
        new AndGate(xLeft, yTop);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a gate with the given top left corner
     * @param x the x co-ordinate of the top left point
     * @param y the y co-ordinate of the top left point
     */
    public AndGate(int x, int y)
    {
        xLeft = x;
        yTop = y;
    }

    /**
     * Draw the gate
     * @param g2 the graphics context
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
        //Main shape
        Point2D.Double p1 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 1/3, yTop);
        Point2D.Double p2 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 1/3, yTop + HEIGHT);
        Point2D.Double p3 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 7/12, yTop);
        Point2D.Double p4 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 7/12, yTop + HEIGHT);

        Line2D.Double verticle = new Line2D.Double(p1, p2);
        Line2D.Double horizontal1 = new Line2D.Double(p1, p3);
        Line2D.Double horizontal2 = new Line2D.Double(p2, p4);

        Arc2D.Double arc = new Arc2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 4/12, yTop, xLeft + WIDTH * 4/12, 
                yTop + HEIGHT * 19/24, 270, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);

        //Output wire
        Point2D.Double p5 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 11/15, yTop + HEIGHT * 1/2);
        Point2D.Double p6 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH, yTop + HEIGHT * 1/2);

        Line2D.Double out = new Line2D.Double(p5, p6);

        //Input wire 1
        Point2D.Double p7 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft, yTop + HEIGHT * 1/3);
        Point2D.Double p8 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 1/3, yTop + HEIGHT * 1/3);

        Line2D.Double in1 = new Line2D.Double(p7, p8);

        //Input wire 2
        Point2D.Double p9 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft, yTop + HEIGHT * 2/3);
        Point2D.Double p10 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft + WIDTH * 1/3, yTop + HEIGHT * 2/3);

        Line2D.Double in2 = new Line2D.Double(p9, p10);

        //Draw
        g2.draw(verticle);
        g2.draw(horizontal1);
        g2.draw(horizontal2);
        g2.draw(arc);
        g2.draw(out);
        g2.draw(in1);
        g2.draw(in2);

    }

}
```

**AndGateComponent.java**
    package andGate;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AndGateComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        AndGate ag = new AndGate(20, 20);

        ag.draw(g2);
    }
}
```

**AndGateViewer**
    package andGate;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AndGateViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.setTitle("And Gate");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        AndGateComponent ag = new AndGateComponent();
        frame.add(ag);
    }
}
```

Comment: what methods do you call when the error occurs? i.o.w. what line triggers the exception?

Comment: I call my own AndGate method and the g2.draw(and) has the error.
It's unable to draw the gate in adder.java (line 46), and casting to Shape at any point the compiler returns a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me out.
All I needed to do was draw the gates in the AdderComponent.java file, not in Adder.java.

The Adder.java class isn't actually needed at all.

**AdderComponent.java**

```
package adder;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import andGate.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AdderComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        AndGate and = new AndGate(20, 20);
        and.draw(g2);
    }
}
```